Java Sound Sequencer Set Tempo Lag
There is an audible lag/delay when setting the tempo. Same result using setTempoFactor or setTempoInBPM.
I have a simple test setup including a sequencer with 1/4 notes and a button that sets the tempo to twice as fast. when i click the button right on the 1/4 note i would expect the sequencer to immediately set the tempo and for the 1/4 notes to become 1/8 notes and stay in time. However there is a significant lag that throws the ticks off time. Any info would be great just throwing this out there... thanks

Show your code please
